# Detect if class has constructor with signature

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17

How can I compile-time detect if a class has a constructor with a given signature? To be specific I would like to do the following:

```
class Archive
{
    // (...)

    template <typename T>
    T Read()
    {
        if constexpr(HasUnarchiveConstructor<T>())
        {
            return T(*this); // constructor accepts reference to Factory
        }
        else
        {
            T t;
            Unarchive(*this, t); // use stand alone function instead. (if this is not available either, compiling fails)
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

There are many sources for detecting functions with certain signatures. I am however unable to convert these to constructors.
[source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature) [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) [source 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975147/check-if-class-has-function-with-signature), and more.

From sources I found I compiled the following to detect if a function has the plus operator:

```
template<typename T>
using HasUnarchiveConstructorImpl = decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>());

template< typename T >
using HasUnarchiveConstructor = std::is_detected<HasUnarchiveConstructorImpl, T>;
```

How can I extend this to the check I want to perform? Or how can I do it in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I extend this to the check I want to perform?

You could use `decltype(...)` on an `T{...}` expression as follows:

```
struct Foo 
{ 
    Foo(Archive&) { }
};

struct Bar
{ 
    // unsupported
};

template<class T>
using HasUnarchiveConstructorImpl = 
    decltype(T{std::declval<Archive&>()});

template <class T>
using HasUnarchiveConstructor = 
    std::experimental::is_detected<HasUnarchiveConstructorImpl, T>;

static_assert(HasUnarchiveConstructor<Foo>::value);
static_assert(!HasUnarchiveConstructor<Bar>::value);
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gu0cWul67ebSSsij)

---

> Or how can I do it in a different way?

See Howard Hinnant's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590149/598696).

Comment: Your answer teached me how to do this myself. Howards answer showed me how I can skip a lot of code(I only have a homebrew is_detected available). Both were very useful.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent implicit conversions from screwing up the detection? I.e. if I have want to check for constructor by pointer, but the other class has a bool constructor, it will still succeed:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zqm29gL1XLBgwlO2

Answer (score 14):

I would use:

```
if constexpr(std::is_constructible<T, Archive&>{})
```

This trait lives in `<type_traits>` and comes ready-made and debugged for you.  There is an entire family of traits to detect variants of this question available for you there.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
using HasUnarchiveConstructor = std::is_constructible<T, Archive&>;
```

See [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rei7HBViGBWgWtXq)