# C++ template specialization with types which have certain interface

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Suppose I have such template:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
   ...
};
```

I want this template can be specialized only if type which will be substituted in place of `T` have certain interface. For example, this type must have such two methods:

```
int send(const char* buffer, size_t size);
int receive(char* buffer, size_t size);
```

How can i make this restrictions on the template?
Thanks for the help!

UPD:

This question is about SFINAE? not about inheretince or class design.

Comment: Don't confuse templates with an abstract base class requirement. If you need a specific set of functions, define that interface as a class and make it a simple typed requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if class has function with signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975147/check-if-class-has-function-with-signature)

Comment: @tadman that assumes that you can add the base class to all the types you are interested in.

Comment: @Caleth That's what multiple-inheritance is all about. Until C++ has protocol support that's how things shake out.

Comment: @tadman what I mean is that you may be receiving objects with those methods from a 3rd party, where you don't control the instantiation, so you can't change the class

Comment: @Caleth That's a valid concern and a good thing to note here. I was suggesting it from an API design perspective if this is something someone has full control over.

Comment: Friends thanks for your comments. This question is about SFINAE, not about inheritance and design of classes. I want to make dispacther that can work with different classes (not necessary my) which provide socket or pipe interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is clearly preferable but since you explicitly asked for SFINAE, here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// std::void_t in C++17
template < typename... >
using void_t = void;


// Check if there is a member function "send" with the signature
// int send(const char*, size_t)
template < typename T >
using send_call_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().send(std::declval<char const *>(), std::declval<size_t>()));

template < typename, typename = void_t<> >
struct is_send_callable : std::false_type {};

template < typename T >
struct is_send_callable< T, void_t< send_call_t<T> > > : std::is_same< send_call_t<T>, int > {};


// Check if there is a member function "receive" with the signature
// int receive(const char*, size_t)
template < typename T >
using recv_call_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().receive(std::declval<char *>(), std::declval<size_t>()));

template < typename, typename = void_t<> >
struct is_recv_callable : std::false_type {};

template < typename T >
struct is_recv_callable< T, void_t< recv_call_t<T> > > : std::is_same< recv_call_t<T>, int > {};


// Make a struct which implements both
struct sndrecv
{
  int send(const char* buffer, size_t size)
  {
    std::cout << "Send: " << buffer << ' ' << size << '\n';
    return 0;
  }

  int receive(char* buffer, size_t size)
  {
    std::cout << "Receive: " << buffer << ' ' << size << '\n';
    return 0;
  }
};


// Disable A if T does not have send and receive
template < typename T, typename >
class A;

template < typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if< is_send_callable<T>::value && is_recv_callable<T>::value >::type >
class A {};


int main() {
  A<sndrecv> a;
//A<int> b; // BOOM!
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The very easy way is to use `T::send` and `T::receive` within `A`, any type not implementing those will result in a compile time failure to instantiate the template. You only need SFINAE to distinguish between specialisations of templates.

e.g.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    void useT(T & theT)
    {
        char buf[20]
        theT.send("Some Thing", 11);
        theT.recieve(buf, 20);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! Can your provide some code or example?

Answer (score 0):

Check if class has method with certain signature is common application of SFINAE principle. For instance you can check [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257382) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87846/7010551).